# scribe with gwt- trying to go to twitter for auth and then come back to my gwt app

Tags: gwt, oauth, scribe

What I am trying to do is this--

(1) User comes to app.html (GWT application) in my website- here he sees many options to login with- like Facebook, Twitter Google Yahoo etc

(2) When he clicks on Twitter (for our example) he is redirected to the twitter site where he authenticates + allows my web app to access his twitter data.

(3) Finally user is redirected via OAuth Call back URL to my site... Here the oauth token and oauth verifier are part of the callback url as parameters... These are now extracted and finally the access token is obtained.

Is such a flow possible? Or do I necessarily have to open twitter auth url in a new window of browser?

Comment: What you describe here is a normal OAuth flow, ergo possible.